# Set button textSize as large as possible without enlarging the button background in android

Tags: android, button, text-size

I would like to set the textSize of my button's text to be as large as possible but limit it in a way that will not change my button dimension which is equal to the resource file.

Do you know any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you

```
// Determine Scaled Density for later calculations
Display dd = ((Activity) m_Context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
dd.getMetrics(dm);
float m_ScaledDensity = dm.scaledDensity;

Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setTypeface(btn.getTypeface());

// W is a very wide character
String sample = "NeedsToFIt"
int maxFont;
for (maxFont= 1
    ; -bounds.top <= btn.getHeight() && bounds.right <= btn.getWidth()
    ; maxFont++) {
  p.setTextSize(maxFont);
  p.getTextBounds(sample, 0, sample.length(), bounds);
}
maxFont = (int) ((maxFont - 1) / m_ScaledDensity);
btn.setTextSize(maxFont);
```

Comment: It didn't work so I debugged it and btn.getHeight() is 0 for me, maybe because my button uses wrap_content and it automatically adjust it to the resource dimensions, also I did not understand why you are dividing by m_ScaledDensity at btn.setTextSize and not dividing at p.setTextsize.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Auto scale textview](https://bitbucket.org/ankri/autoscaletextview/src) for that.